For which $a, b$ is the function $(1 + |x|^a + |y|^b)^{-1}$ integrable?
I'm struggling with this exercise from my class:
For which $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$  is the function $f (x, y) = \frac{1}{1 + |x|^a + |y|^b}$ integrable over $\mathbb{R}^2$?
So far I thought about evaluating as follows:
$\frac{1}{1 + |x|^a + |y|^b} < \frac{1}{1 + |x|^a + |y|^a} < \frac{1}{2|x|^a}$, given $a < b, 1< |x| < |y|$. Since $\frac{1}{2|x|^a}$ is integrable for $a > 1$, $f$ is also integrable with $\max(a, b) > 1$ on $|x|, |y| > 1$.
How can I finish this proof for $|x| < 1$ and $|y| < 1$?

Dropping the 1 in the denominator isn't a great idea. You just bounded a bounded function by an unbounded one.

Expanding @UmbertoP.'s comment. As in single variable calculus, if you want to bound $\frac1{1+x^a}$, you have to be careful. Take for instance $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^a} dx$, then it's better to first split the interval of integration as $\int_0^1+\int_1^{\infty}$ and in the second integral, drop the $1$ in the denominator

@SineoftheTime thats why I only considered $|x|, |y| > 1$. What could I do for $|x| < 1$, $|y| < 1$?

You always have $\frac 1{1+|x|^a} \le 1$ regardless of the value of $x$.

This question is similar to: Determine under for what values $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ are this integral is finite.. Found using Approach$0$ https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%20%2B%20%7Cx%7C%5Ea%20%2B%20%7Cy%7C%5Eb%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegrable&p=1
